# What species of frog is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, species

I was walking around outside my house when I found this little guy clinging to the outer wall of my house. The house in question is located in Indiana, United States. What is interesting to note is that the skin that is normally covered up by the frog's hind legs is yellow, but the rest of its belly is not, and this can only be seen when the frog is spreading its hind legs. You can see some of the yellow skin poking out from behind the left hind leg in the picture. This was at night, and the frog couldn't have been longer than an average person's index finger.

[image]

[image]